# Binary distributions of old (1.0 - 2.5) versions of Scala?

Tags: scala

The [Scala website](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads) says:

> For historical and testing purposes, we also keep an archive of
>   previous releases (currently since version 2.5). Prior versions of
>   Scala, from 0.9.x to 2.4.x, have been archived offline.

Is there any way to get these versions? The source code is available in the git repo, but binaries would be nice.

**EDIT:**

I found some old versions at archive.org, but the oldest that I could get was 1.1.1.3 from http://web.archive.org/web/20040603140225/http://scala.epfl.ch/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 3):

It turns out, if one looks hard enough, everything from 1.0.0-b4 can be found on [archive.org](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20040515000000%2a/http://scala.epfl.ch/downloads/index.html). Unfortunately, some version in between are nowhere to be found, for example 2.3.x and 2.0.x. The question remains why they aren't published on http://scala-lang.org.